# Sum two arrays of numeric values whose dimension is up to 100 in R

Tags: r, arrays, sum, dimension

"Sum two arrays of numeric values whose dimension is up to 100 in R" is the question given to me.

As a beginner, does it mean the final array has 100D?
Suppose it would be correct, and I'm providing the random values below.
If I'm wrong, please let me know.

```
array1 <- array(1:10, c(2, 2, 100))
array2 <- array(11:20, c(2, 2, 100))
```

If I misunderstood the data science words, please cannot be happier to get advice from you.

Also, please help me to get the answer to this problem in R.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same dimension to be returned, use

```
array1 + array2
```

Comment: Oh, my...so simple. thanks! @akrun